# Dispatch specific values to reducer from array on button click

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm attempting to send a theme to my reducer with an onClick event. However, I am unsure how to pass the data from my button to my `handleTheme` function to dispatch the values of the chosen array to my reducer.

Here are my two themes:

```js
 const themes = [
    {
      themeTitle: "Theme 1",
      backgroundColor: "white",
      border: "none",
      buttonBackgroundColor: "black",
      color: "white",
      searchBackgroundColor: "black",
      fontFamily: selectedFont,
    },
    {
      themeTitle: "Theme 2",
      backgroundColor: "white",
      border: "none",
      buttonBackgroundColor: "#1A77F2",
      searchBackgroundColor: "#1A77F2",
      color: "white",
      fontFamily: selectedFont,
    },
  ];
```

Here is my onClick function:

```js
 // dispatch theme to reducer
  const handleTheme = () => {
    if()
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_THEME",
      item: themes[0]
      },
    });
  };
```

And here is how I am rendering the buttons on the webpage:

```js
{themes.map((t) => (
          <button onClick={handleTheme} id={t.themeTitle}>
            {t.themeTitle}
          </button>
        ))}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ? You can pass the value like this -> `onClick={()=> handleTheme(t)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man if you are using hooks, you should read this section https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks.

But to save your time here we go.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
...

//inside your hook

const dispatch = useDispatch();

dispatch({
      type: "SET_THEME",
      item: themes[0]
      },
    })
```